# How do I read without getting getting a neck cramp?

Tags: comfort, books

Whenever I read, I get neck cramps. I tried looking down at the book, I tried lying on my stomach and looking forward at the book, but I still get cramps.

Is there a trick to not get cramps?

Answer (score 7):

Though I haven't tried them there are prism reading glasses that might make it more comfortable ([something like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RZNBF4), perhaps), or you might try large print text that would allow a more comfortable reading position. Could the issue be tenseness, however? Try relaxation techniques.

Comment: Nice answer. I recall reading somewhere that these glasses were recommended for those undergoing treatment for [scoliosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoliosis), which includes wearing a back brace that does not allow for looking down.

Answer (score 5):

Try sitting on a chair, then putting a big cushion or pillow (or two) on your lap. The pillow will raise the book level higher, and you won't have to strain your arms or neck to read it.